# CarrierWave :thumb method breaking images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rmagick

I am using CarrierWave to upload images.  I am also using this functionality in ActiveAdmin.

I followed the RailsCast and everything is working up to the point where the RMagick gem is coming into play.  Before resizing an image and just getting the image by calling:

"<%= image_tag @client.image_url.to_s %>"

When I go to resize an image, the image breaks.  The code I have in my image_uploader.rb file is the same as Ryan Bates in where I am doing the following:

"version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
  
end"

Then, when adding the :thumb method to my previous erb tag with the following:

"<%= image_tag @client.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>"

The images break.  The interesting thing for me is that I have done this process multiple times, but this is the first time I have tried using CarrierWave and RMagick with Active Admin.

Comment: What do you mean with that it 'breaks the image'?

Comment: I think what the original poster means is that after trying to implement the :thumb method - when the view that displays the images is loaded - the image does not appear - and is instead replaced by that icon that indicates that the image will not load. I am having this same problem - does anyone know a workaround?